# When $a\cdot b < 0 < a\cdot c$?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, analysis, vectors

Let $a, b, c\in\mathbb{R}^3$ three nonnull vectors.
Assume that:

$$b\perp c.$$

I would like to understand if there exists a suitable condition on $a$ which guarantees that
$$a\cdot b < 0 < a\cdot c.$$

I know that this means that the projection of $a$ over $b$ is negative and the projection of $a$ over $c$ is positive, but I was wondering if there is a condition on $a$ which can guarantee that the above inequality holds true.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You could specifically use the vector
$$
a = \frac{c}{\|c\|} - \frac{b}{\|b\|}
$$

Comment: @BenGrossmann, what do you mean?

Comment: I mean that this vector $a$ is guaranteed to satisfy $a \cdot b < 0 < a \cdot c$

Comment: @BenGrossmann, what the condition $b\perp c$ is used for?

Comment: if $a$ in the same plane as $b,c$ you want to have an acute angle between $a,c$ and an obtuse one between $a,b$. So if you identifiy $b/||b||=x$ and $c/||c||=y$ then $a$ will be in the $x<0,y>0$ quadrant for instance. That can probably be generalized to $R^3$ I guess ?

Comment: Since $b \perp c$, we can form a coordinate system with $b$ the direction of the positive $x$-axis, and $c$ as the direction of the positive $y$-axis, The positive $z$-axis in the direction of $b\times c$. Your condition is equivalent to saying that the $x$-coordinate of $a$ is negative and the $y$-coordinate is positive. The $z$-coordinate can be anything. That is, the projection of $a$ onto the $xy$-plane is in the 2nd quadrant.

Comment: To answer your question to Ben Grossmann, the only use of $b \perp c$ here, beyond ensuring $b$ and $c$ are not parallel, is for your comfort. You get to think of it in terms of a nice familiar rectangular coordinate system instead of a non-rectangular one. But the only difference geometrically is that the two half-spaces whose intersection $a$ lies in have boundary planes meeting at a right angle instead of some arbitrary angle.